# Setting vim's height inside screen

Tags: linux, vim, gnu-screen

I have what I thought to be a pretty good terminal workflow going. I set up screen to split horizontally, and then resize the bottom portion to ten lines. But when opening up vim on the upper portion, content is cut off from the top because vim thinks that my window height is 100%, when really it's window height - 10 lines (being taken up from the bottom screen).

How can I tell vim that it should only display window height - 10 lines of space?

Here is my .screenrc:

```
startup_message off
chdir /var/www/
screen -t "Development"
split
focus
chdir ~/
screen -t "Shell"
resize 10
focus
```

As a side note, for what it's worth I'm SSHing into a remote server from Mac OS X 10.8 using terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by adding `altscreen on` to my .screenrc